# Integrating Jenkins with phantomjs for selenium webdriver test

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I am integrating jenkins with phantomjs to run my selenium test scripts. Phantomjs is installed in my jenkins server and ghost driver is running in port 8090. But, still my tests were skipped and it throws an exception as

> The path to the driver executable must be set by the
>   phantomjs.binary.path capability/system property/PATH variable; for
>   more information, see https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki. The
>   latest version can be downloaded from
>   http://phantomjs.org/download.html"

My jenkins runs in centos.

My code looks like below,

```
@BeforeClass
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
      dCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
      driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dCaps);
      baseUrl = "";
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
```

Comment: So where is the code that sets the path to the PhantomJS binary?

Comment: Tim, Now I've added a plugin named env inject to CI environment and injected that phantomjs binary path in that.Now it works fine for me. thankx for your concern Tim..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The path to the driver executable must be set by the
>   phantomjs.binary.path capability/system property/PATH variable;

You  should explicitly  point where you are placing phantomJm exe on the machine where tests asre supposed to be executed. So I've found out 2 ways how to resolve it:

1) possibility #1  ( point to  it  in code explicitly)

```
@BeforeClass
    public void seleniumGrridUponGhostDriver() throws MalformedURLException {

        File phantomjs = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")+File.separator+"phantomjs-1.9.7");


        DesiredCapabilities dcaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dcaps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);


        dcaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, phantomjs.getAbsolutePath());

   this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://162.243.175.134:8080"), dcaps);


        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //page instances init()
        loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
        homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, FacebookUserPage.class);
    }
```

2) possibility #2,using   [PhantomJS Windows/Mac OS X/Linux native binary embedder](https://github.com/anthavio/phanbedder)

pom.xml dependecies:

```
<!--substituting   phanbedder  with local Phanbedder implementation-->
                     <dependency>
                 <groupId>net.anthavio</groupId>
                 <artifactId>phanbedder-1.9.7</artifactId>
                 <version>1.0.0</version>
             </dependency>



             <dependency>
                 <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
                 <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
                 <version>1.1.0</version>
             </dependency>
```

code:

```
 import net.anthavio.phanbedder.Phanbedder;

 @BeforeClass
    public void seleniumGrridUponGhostDriver() throws MalformedURLException {


       File phantomjs = Phanbedder.unpack(); //Phanbedder to the rescue!
  DesiredCapabilities dcaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dcaps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);


        dcaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, phantomjs.getAbsolutePath());

   this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://162.243.175.134:8080"), dcaps);


        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //page instances init()
        loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
        homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, FacebookUserPage.class);
    }
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this too, and had already built Jenkins on Linux and wanted to use that installation. Using System Properties didn't work (for the service, or even the global Maven properties in Jenkins).

I didn't like the programmatic approach above, as that tied the solution to platform specific configuration.

In the end, what did work was putting it in the POM.

> ```
>                 <plugin>
>                     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>                     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>                     <configuration>
>                         <systemProperties>
>                             <phantomjs.binary.path>/usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs</phantomjs.binary.path>
>                         </systemProperties>
>                     </configuration>
>                 </plugin>
> ```

Here is a more detailed description of what worked for me (not my article):
http://balamaci.ro/continous-integration-with-jenkins-docker-ansible-webdriver/